# Admob doesn't work in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

Hi I'm working on a phonegap application for android. I'm having trouble integrating the admob script since it doesn't show any ads. I think I have all the permissions in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.mauriziopz.disegna"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DisegnaActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

This is my test page, which doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var admob_vars = {
         pubid: 'MY_ID', // publisher id
         test: true, // test mode, set to false if non-test mode
         manual_mode: true
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var a = _admob.fetchAd(document.getElementById('admob_ad'));
    }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
Test
<div id='admob_ad'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I Tried both in manual mode and not, but never was able to get it working.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: no, I switched to http://www.smaato.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on this, but i think you have to execute your var a.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     var a = _admob.fetchAd(document.getElementById('admob_ad'));
    //trigger the var
     a;
}
and add body onLoad to execute
<body onLoad="onDeviceReady()">
```

It's working here, like this:

```
<body onLoad="doIt()">
<div id="admob_ad"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     function doIt() {
    _admob.fetchAd(document.getElementById('admob_ad'));
     //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
              }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@MaurizioPz: You need to add an activity in the android manifest file for Admob as follows:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

</application>
```

Also make sure you are using the latest Admob SDK.